# Potential problems with the Gaußian Elimination method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

We can use Gaußian Elimination (GE) to help us solve larger systems of equations. If we have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$, where $\mathbb{K} \in \{ \mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb G \}$, what are the potential problems with using GE?

I'm pretty sure we run into rounding errors if the values in the matrix have a large difference between them, i.e., if $a_{0,0}=0.00002$ and $a_{0,4}=120000$, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Sorry but what is $\mathbb G$ ? By the way, Gauss is normally used on square matrices.

Comment: $\mathbb{G}$ is used for floating point numbers. Yes, but you could still use Gauß for rectangle matrices, however you would end up with either an overdetermined to underdetermined system.

Comment: Oh, do you refer to G-floats ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaussian elimination is well-known to be sensitive to numerical rounding errors, especially with ill-conditioned matrices. To reduce this problem, two pivoting strategies (namely *partial* and *total*) are classical.

There is a complete theory of roundoff errors in linear algebra and in Gaussian elimination in particular. But this is not a simple topic, I have to refer you to a textbook. (E.g. Matrix Computation by G. Golub & al.)